# Where should I put the bean definition in Spring MVC project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am not familiar with Spring MVC. I found that there should be a root application context and web application context in a typical spring MVC project. These two xml files (when using the xml approach), would usually be put into the WEB-INF folder.

I am confuse, that what is the primary function of the root application context in the spring mvc project? Is it exactly the application context used for defining bean (using dependency injection)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root application context is there to define all application related beans. Example Services and Repositories.

The Web application is there to specify your controllers, view resolver and any web related things.

Your Web application will be able to access your root application, but not the other way around, enforcing a "separation of concerns"

However, more and more, people are ignoring this notation and just defining everything in a single root application context.

Answer (score 4):

You can find good explanation in spring [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html)

[image: DispatcherServlet]

This image from there. ApplicationContext is configure the whole spring project and it is start point for project. It is using defining beans.